# How do I add an object to a channel from a goroutine that is receiving data from that channel?

Tags: go, concurrency, producer-consumer, goroutine

Basically, I am trying to write a concurrent sitemap crawler using goroutines. One sitemap can contain links to multiple sitemaps which can contain links to other sitemaps etc.

Right now, this is my design:

```
worker:
     - receives url from channel
     - processesUrl(url)
processUrl:
     for each link in lookup(url):
         - if link is sitemap:
                channel <- url
           else:
               print(url)
main:
    - create 10 workers
    - chanel <- root url
```

the problem is that the worker won't accept a new url from the channel until processUrl() is finished and processUrl won't finish until a worker accepts a new url from the channel if it is adding a url to the channel. What concurrent design can I use to add the url to a task queue without a channel and without busy-waiting or without waiting for `channel <- url`?

Here is the actual code if it helps:

```
func (c *SitemapCrawler) worker() {
    for {
        select {
        case url := <-urlChan:
            fmt.Println(url)
            c.crawlSitemap(url)
        }
    }
}
func crawlUrl(url string) {
    defer crawlWg.Done()
    crawler := NewCrawler(url)
    for i := 0; i < MaxCrawlRate*20; i++ {
        go crawler.worker()
    }
    crawler.getSitemaps()
    pretty.Println(crawler.sitemaps)
    crawler.crawlSitemaps()
}
func (c SitemapCrawler) crawlSitemap(url string) {
    c.limiter.Take()
    resp, err := MakeRequest(url)
    if err != nil || resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        crawlWg.Done()
        return
    }
    var resp_txt []byte
    if strings.Contains(resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"), "html") {
        crawlWg.Done()
        return
    } else if strings.Contains(url, ".gz") || resp.Header.Get("Content-Encoding") == "gzip" {
        reader, err := gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            crawlWg.Done()
            panic(err)
        } else {
            resp_txt, err = ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
            if err != nil {
                crawlWg.Done()
                panic(err)
            }
        }
        reader.Close()
    } else {
        resp_txt, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            //panic(err)
            crawlWg.Done()
            return
        }
    }
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()

    d, err := libxml2.ParseString(string(resp_txt))
    if err != nil {
        crawlWg.Done()
        return
    }
    results, err := d.Find("//*[contains(local-name(), 'loc')]")
    if err != nil {
        crawlWg.Done()
        return
    }
    locs := results.NodeList()
    printLock.Lock()
    for i := 0; i < len(locs); i++ {
        newUrl := locs[i].TextContent()
        if strings.Contains(newUrl, ".xml") {
            crawlWg.Add(1)
            //go c.crawlSitemap(newUrl)
            urlChan <- newUrl
        } else {
            fmt.Println(newUrl)
        }
    }
    printLock.Unlock()

    crawlWg.Done()
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a larger buffer

Comment: `go func() { channel <- url }()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write operations to channels are blocking when the channel is not buffered.

To create a buffered channel:

```
urlChan := make(chan string, len(allUrls))
```

When this channel is full however, write operations will block again.

Alternatively you could use a switch. When the write 'fails' it will immediately fall through to default

```
select {
case urlChan <- url:
    fmt.Println("received message")
default:
    fmt.Println("no activity")
}
```

To have a timeout on writing to the channel do the following

```
select {
case urlChan <- url:
    fmt.Println("received message")
case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
    fmt.Println("timed out")
}
```

Or finally put the write event in a separate go channel

```
func write() {
    urlChan <- url
}

go write()
```

Comment: So if you have an indefinite number of urls in the crawl space, would I just set an arbitrarily high buffer for the channel or is #3 my only option?

Comment: You could just use a large buffer, but this feels rather hacky. #3 Seems preferable to that. Alternatively you could forego the entire channel queue approach and write the urls you find to a database (Something like redis maybe?). Each worker could then query the database for uncompleted url's. This has the added benefit of not losing all your progress when the applications closes. Another option would be to pass around a mutex slice, This seems pretty complicated though.